# What ocular disorders fit within the scopes of practice of both ophthalmologists and optometrists?

Tags: optometry, opthalmology

Which ophthalmic conditions [overlap](https://www.nvisioncenters.com/education/optometrist-vs-ophthalmologist/#overlap) the most in the scopes of practice between  ophthalmologists and optometrists? What scopes or areas of practice are most shared by ophthalmologists and optometrists?

I read [here](https://www.healthshare.com.au/questions/48183-what-is-the-difference-between-an-optometrist-and-an-ophthalmologist):

> There is a fair deal of overlap in the work that Ophthalmologists and Optometrists do

And [here](https://www.optometristoakville.ca/blog/difference-optician-ophthalmologist-optometrist):

> Making the confusion worse is the fact that there is some overlap in what each one does.

And [here](https://doi.org/10.1111/cxo.12145):

> Ophthalmology has also provided refractive care for at least the last 100 years, in which time there has been considerable overlap in the roles undertaken by optometrists and ophthalmologists.

However, I can't find a list of the particulars of the overlaps.